# Como resolver o erro "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence" quando a lista está vazia?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Apareceu esse erro quando eu estava testando meu programa, mais precisamente quando os valores do `input` não satisfazem as condições impostas:

```
n = int(input())
listaVelocidade = []

for _ in range(n):
    velocidades = int(input())
    listaVelocidade.append(velocidades)
    classe1 = []
    classe2 = []
    classe3 = []

    for velocidade in listaVelocidade:
        if velocidade < 10:
            classe1.append(velocidade)

        elif velocidade >= 10 and velocidade < 20:
            classe2.append(velocidade)

        elif velocidade > 20:
            classe3.append(velocidade)

if None in classe1 or classe2 or classe3:
    classe1.append(0)
    classe2.append(0)
    classe3.append(0)

print(max(classe1), max(classe2), max(classe3))
```

Notem que eu coloquei uma condição para verificar se a lista está vazia, mas isso não funcionou, também anteriormente tentei colocar um `else` e adicionar 0 nas listas se as condições anteriores não forem atendidas.

OObs: peço que testem colocando, por exemplo, 6 como primeiro valor de entrada e posteriormente uma sequencia de 1, outra observação é que se nenhuma condição for satisfeita, tenho que retornar 0.

Answer (score 2):

O erro "***ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence***" está indicando que alguma - ou todas - as sequências estão vazias. Para você corrigir este problema você deve trocar o bloco...

```
if None in classe1 or classe2 or classe3:
    classe1.append(0)
    classe2.append(0)
    classe3.append(0)
```

...por:

```
if len(classe1) == 0:
    classe1.append(0)
if len(classe2) == 0:
    classe2.append(0)
if len(classe3) == 0:
    classe3.append(0)
```

Outra coisa, o seu código está mal indentado. Além disso, o seu último bloco `elif` está errado.

Uma forma correta para resolver esta questão é:

```
n = int(input())
listaVelocidade = []

for _ in range(n):
    velocidades = int(input())
    listaVelocidade.append(velocidades)

classe1 = []
classe2 = []
classe3 = []

for velocidade in listaVelocidade:
    if velocidade < 10:
        classe1.append(velocidade)
    elif 10 <= velocidade < 20:
        classe2.append(velocidade)
    else:
        classe3.append(velocidade)

if len(classe1) == 0:
    classe1.append(0)
if len(classe2) == 0:
    classe2.append(0)
if len(classe3) == 0:
    classe3.append(0)

print(max(classe1), max(classe2), max(classe3))
```

Observe que ao executarmos este código, devemos inserir a **quantidade** de velocidades que iremos inserir e, em seguida, digitar `enter`. Posteriormente, devemos digitar cada uma das **n-ezimas** velocidades e, para cada velocidade, pressionar `enter`.

Tendo terminado de inserir todas as velocidades, o código irá classificar as velocidades, agrupando-as em **classes**. Posteriormente, cada classe será verificada e se alguma delas estiver vazia, será adicionado o valor **0** na mesma.

Por fim será exibido a máxima velocidade de cada classe.

Answer (score 2):

Isso aqui:

```
if None in classe1 or classe2 or classe3:
```

**Não** faz o que você pensa que faz. Na verdade, o que você tem são 3 condições:

- `None in classe1`: isso verifica se `None` está na lista `classe1` (ou seja, se `None` foi inserido anteriormente na lista). Mas como você só insere números, o `None` nunca estará na lista, então essa condição sempre será falsa
- `classe2`: sim, [uma lista (e qualquer outro valor) pode ser usada em um contexto *booleano*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). No caso, se a lista for vazia, é considerado um valor falso, e se não for vazia, é considerado verdadeiro.
- `classe3`: idem

Portanto, a primeira condição sempre será falsa, mas se `classe2` ou `classe3` tiverem pelo menos um elemento, serão consideradas `True` e entrará no `if`, já que uma expressão que tem várias condições com `or` é considerada verdadeira se qualquer uma das condições for verdadeira (imprima as listas depois deste `if` e veja você mesmo que se `classe2` ou `classe3` não estiver vazia, sempre é adicionado um zero).

E é por isso que ele não entra no `if` quando as listas `classe2` e `classe3` são vazias: porque uma lista vazia é avaliada como `False`, e como já dito, a primeira condição também é falsa porque `None` não foi adicionado em `classe1` (então todas as condições são falsas e não entra no `if`).

---

Mas sinceramente, isso que você pensou em fazer é - na minha opinião - uma grande gambiarra. Se a ideia é retornar zero caso a lista seja vazia, não tem porque adicionar um elemento artificialmente só para não dar erro. Eu acho mais simples verificar se a lista é vazia:

```
n = int(input())

classe1 = []
classe2 = []
classe3 = []
for _ in range(n):
    velocidade = int(input())
    if velocidade < 10:
        classe1.append(velocidade)
    elif velocidade < 20:
        classe2.append(velocidade)
    else:
        classe3.append(velocidade)

def maior(lista):
    if len(lista) == 0: # se a lista é vazia, retorna zero
        return 0
    return max(lista) # lista não é vazia, retorna o max()

print(maior(classe1), maior(classe2), maior(classe3))
```

Criei uma função para facilitar: ela verifica se a lista é vazia (se for, retorna zero), e se não for, usa `max`. Isso é melhor do que adicionar um elemento a mais. **Claro que também podemos discutir se faz sentido retornar um valor artifical qualquer** (pois e se for digitado somente zeros, como você vai saber se o zero é o maior valor que foi de fato digitado ou se caiu no caso de lista vazia? Talvez seja o caso de não retornar nada e imprimir uma mensagem de erro, por exemplo), mas enfim, inserir um valor artificial "*só para o `max` não dar erro*" me parece uma opção pior.

Removi a lista `listaVelocidade`, pois parece que não estava sendo usada para nada (apenas para guardar as velocidades, para depois só serem inseridas em uma das outras listas, então me parece meio redundante; eu achei mais simples inserir o valor direto nas respectivas listas).

E criei as listas apenas uma vez, antes do `for`. Você estava  criando elas dentro do `for`, ou seja, a cada iteração elas eram recriadas novamente, o que não faz sentido. Crie uma vez fora do *loop* e dentro dele apenas insira os elementos.

Repare também nos `if`'s: se não entrou no `if velocidade < 10` é porque o valor com certeza é maior ou igual a 10, então não precisa testar isso de novo no `elif`.
E se não entrou no `elif velocidade < 20`, é porque com certeza é maior ou igual a 20, então não precisa testar de novo no `else`:

```
if velocidade < 10:
    # se entrou aqui, é porque é menor que 10
    classe1.append(velocidade)
# se não entrou no if acima, é porque com certeza é >= 10, então não precisa testar de novo no elif
elif velocidade < 20:
    classe2.append(velocidade)
# se não entrou no if nem no elif, é porque com certeza é >= 20, então não precisa testar de novo
else:
    classe3.append(velocidade)
```

Answer (score 2):

Veja o algoritmo de seu código:

```
Leia o número de entradas e coloque em n
Inicialize a lista de velocidades listaVelocidade

Itere sobre o número de entradas...
   Leia uma velocidade
   Inicialize a lista de classe de velocidade classe1 
   Inicialize a lista de classe de velocidade classe2
   Inicialize a lista de classe de velocidade classe3 
   Para cada velocidade em listaVelocidade
      Verifique se a velocidade é menor que 10
         Se sim a adicione velocidade em classe1
      Se não se a velocidade é maior ou igual a 10 e menor que 20
         Se sim a adicione velocidade em classe2
      Se não se a velocidade é maior que 20
         Se sim a adicione velocidade em classe3

Verifique se None está em classe1 ou classe2 não está vazia ou classe3 não está vazia
    Adicione 0 a classe1
    Adicione 0 a classe2
    Adicione 0 a classe3

Imprima o maior valor de classe1, o maior valor de classe2, o maior valor de classe3
```

Repare que logo após ler uma velocidade o código reinicializa as listas `classe1`, `classe2` e `classe3` ou seja a cada nova velocidade inserida no sistema os valores inseridos anteriormente são perdidos então toda vez que entra com uma nova velocidade é preciso reiterar a lista de velocidades e as reclassificar.

Durante a reclassificação das velocidades há outro problema há uma condição que:

- Verifica se a velocidade é menor que 10.
- Verifica se a velocidade é maior ou igual a 10 e menor que 20.
- Verifica se a velocidade é maior que 20.
- **Mas não existe uma condição** que capture uma velocidade igual a 20!

Na última verificação a condição:

```
Verifique se None está em classe1 ou classe2 não está vazia ou classe3 não está vazia
```

Essa expressão não funciona da maneira que espera veja um teste bem ingênuo:

```
>>> print(bool(None in [] or [] or []))
False
```

Ou seja mesmo se `classe1`, `classe2` e `classe3` fossem listas vazias a condição não seria atendida.

Como solução seria melhor reescrever o seu algoritmo removendo as redundâncias e aprimorando as estruturas de dados assim evitando que tenha que fazer reiterações de dados um leque de comparações para tapar os furos. Para facilitar será utilizado um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) que é estrutura de mapeamento na forma chave/valor e a [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) que compara uma condição e essa for verdadeira retorna o lado esquerdo da expressão e falsa retorna o lado direito.

```
#Inicicializa a estrutura de dados que abrigará e classificará as velocidade em classes.
velocidades = {"classe1":[0], "classe2":[0], "classe3":[0]}

#Lê a quantidade de entradas e itera essa quantidade...
for _ in range(int(input("Quantidade de dados: "))):
    v = int(input("Digite a velocidade: "))                         #...lê uma velocidade e armazena e v.
    c = "classe1" if v < 10 else "classe2" if v < 20 else "classe3" #...classifica a velocidade, se menor que 10 é classe1, 
                                                                    #se menor que 20 e maior ou igual a 10 é classe2,
                                                                    #o que sobrar(maior ou igual a 20) é classe3. 
    velocidades[c].append(v)                                        #...Adiciona a velocidade a sua respectiva classe.

print([max(velocidades[c]) for c in velocidades])                   #Itera pelas chaves dicionário velocidade obtendo e imprimindo o maior valor.
```

Teste o exemplo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/gRRrlo)